# Canvas. Почему Y в 2 раза больше X?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Рисую простую линию:

```
var example = $(".line1")[0],
    ctx = example.getContext('2d');

ctx.setLineDash([4, 2]);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(269, 107);
ctx.strokeStyle = "white";   
ctx.stroke();
```

Размер холста (canvas) 269*269.
Нужно нарисовать линию по диагонали.

Если я указываю ctx.lineTo(269, 107), то по координате Y линия уходит
вниз в середине, а если ctx.lineTo(269, 107), то всё нормально.
Почему Y в 2 раза больше X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что высота и ширина канвы указана в css-свойствах, а нужно в аттрибутах

```
<canvas width="269px" height="269px"></canvas
```

Comment: Почему нужно в аттрибутах?

Comment: Потому что это единственное работающее решение